# sqlalchemy: Making schema reflection find/use a custom type for all instances

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to override the SQLAlchemy `DATETIME2` type (from MS SQL Server) to discard extra digits of subsecond precision if necessary to coerce to a native Python datetime type, as described in [Replacing the Bind Result Processing of Existing Types](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/custom_types.html#replacing-the-bind-result-processing-of-existing-types) section of the docs, like so:

```
import re
import sqlalchemy.dialects as sa_dialects

class TruncatingPrecisionDATETIME2(sa_dialects.mssql.base.DATETIME2):
    __visit_name__ = 'DATETIME2'
    _reg = re.compile(r"(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)(?:\.(\d{0,6})\d*)?")

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if isinstance(value, util.string_types):
            return datetime.time(*[
                int(x or 0)
                for x in self._reg.match(value).groups()])
        else:
            return value

    def adapt(self, impltype):
        return TruncatingPrecisionDATETIME2()
```

However, when I call `meta.reflect()`, and inspect the type of one a column of type `DATETIME2` in the database, it's an instance of `sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.base.DATETIME2` rather than `TruncatingPrecisionDATETIME2`. What do I need to do to change this globally for all DATETIME2 instances?

Comment: The link you posted doesn't seem to necessarily imply that a reflected type itself would be changed to the subclass itself, only that the bind result processing would be replaced. Did you check whether the processing got (or didn't get) invisibly overridden. If it didn't, did you try overriding the `result_processor` method (as originally indicated), instead of `process_result_value`? While they're normally equivalent, I'm not sure if this is so in every single case, particularly when subclassing a native type directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably unofficial as hell, and I'm not sure it would even work on MSSQL as opposed to PostgreSQL ([as this changelog might seem to suggest](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/changelog/changelog_08.html?highlight=ischema_names)), but by replacing the 'datetime2' item on the `sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.base.ischema_names` dictionary by your custom subclass, you may be able to override the SQLAlchemy type used for all reflections of that type, if the official, recommended way of modifying result processing fails.